# Displaying drop down options name instead of their ids in angular javascript

Tags: angularjs

I'm using ng-option="x.id as x.name for x in data"

I'm having problem with drop down value in angular ng-option.

```
$scope.data=[
             {id:'1',name:'a'},
             {id:'2',name:'b'},
             {id:'3',name:'c'},
             {id:'4',name:'d'},
             {id:'5',name:'e'}
         ];
```

Drop down loaded with name a,b,c,d,e initially.but when I save a record, it saved in database but when I try to retrieve record instead of showing name it showed me ids 1,2,3,4,5 against their record.

So please help me out.

Comment: i am not sure, check backend code that id you are storing should be string type not number.

Comment: backend code is fine.